# Can't get org.reflections.Reflections to work, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, annotations, noclassdeffounderror

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with Reflections. So here's an example, I have a package `testreflections.test`, with the classes `Main` and `TestClass` inside it.

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("testreflections.test");
        //Reflections reflections = new Reflections("testreflections.test.TestClass");//I also tried this
        Set<Method> resources =
            reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.junit.Test.class);

        System.out.println(resources.size());

         for (Method set : resources) {
             System.out.println(set.toString());
         }
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is a test");
    }
}
```

Now, I'm simply supposed to get get all the methods with the junit Test annotation (which would just be 1). This should add the one to the set, and print out the appropriate info for it. However, eclipse spits out this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/bytecode/ClassFile
at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:100)
at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:24)
at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:30)
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:238)
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:204)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:129)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:170)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:143)
at testreflections.test.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.bytecode.ClassFile
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

Comment: org.reflections.Reflections is a third party (i.e. non-standard Java) library which apparently has dependiencies which you did not resolve. Why not use package `java.lang.reflect`?

Comment: I just want to be able to retrieve methods with specific annotations. Can I do that with java.lang.reflect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to add [Javaassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) to the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to resolve the dependencies of `org.reflections.Reflections`. The easiest way is to use maven as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/). If not, the required classpath is described [here](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/wiki/ClasspathNotes). Make sure to download all required jar files and include them in the classpath of your Eclipse project.

In my comment I missed the part that you only want to find annotations. With standard Java you could use the `getDeclaredAnnotations()` method of `java.lang.reflect.Method`. But it is not that simple to gather all methods.

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
 --jars  /hydra-analytics/gobblin-dist/lib/reflections-0.9.10.jar,/hydra-analytics/gobblin-dist/lib/guava-retrying-2.0.0.jar,/hydra-analytics/gobblin-dist/lib/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar, ...
```

with command